# Java/SQL Creating custom sequence/creating a sequence based on two sequences

Tags: java, oracle

I have a requirement of creating a unique cyclic sequence which is the concatenation of two individual sequences.

Sequence 1 range is from- 1001 to 1040
Sequence 2 range is from- 220 to 240

The logic to generate the sequence is first increment sequence 2, keeping sequence 1 as-is. Once sequence 2 reaches 240, need to increment sequence 1.

The sequence will be something like below:-

1001-220
1001-221
1001-222
....
....
1001-240
1002-220
1002-221
1002-222
....
....
....
....
1040-240
1001-220

This is pretty simple if there is just one process/JVM that needs this sequencing, in which case I can just have two static variables and implement this logic.

But the sequences can be used by multiple processes sitting on different JVMs and hence needs to be thread-safe.

The next thought I had was to use Oracle DB sequences for both. But this can miss out some sequence numbers due to multiple parallel calls coming from different systems.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is it a requirement that sequence numbers are never missed?  Are you storing these values in the database?

Comment: Yes, the sequence numbers cannot be missed. I don't have a requirement of storing the values in DB, but to just return the sequences as part of web service response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your two sequences are trivially mappable to a simple sequence of integers, i.e.:

```
 1 -> 1001-220
 2 -> 1001-221
 etc.
```

To calculate the two values given any integer value, use the following formulae:

```
n -> TRUNC(1001+n/22) || '-' || (MOD(n-1,21)+220)
```

e.g.

```
26 -> TRUNC(1001+26/22) || '-' || (MOD(26-1,21)+220) -> 1002-224
```

Secondly, sequences in Oracle can never be guaranteed to be gapless; only unique. To make a gapless sequence generator you must introduce serialization, e.g. a lock, to ensure that only one session can get the next value at any one time.

Comment: This is a clean solution, something what I was thinking about but had no idea how to implement. For generating the value of n, I will use an Oracle sequence with NOCACHE so as to minimize the risk of gaps. As you said, this won't guarantee "gaplessness", but losing out a few numbers compared to dealing with locks is way better(at least in my case). Thanks @Jeffrey